# Bounds of sin(x) where x is rational

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Hello all I am starting an analysis course at my university, and we were asked to justify why Sup(S) and Inf(S) is 1 and -1 respectively for the set

$$\ S = \{\sin(x): x \in \mathbb{Q}\} $$

I try to prove by contradiction that there cannot exist an upper bound M that is smaller than 1 however I don't know where to proceed from saying there exists a $\sin(\frac{p}{q}) > M$ that is in S.

Comment: Suggestion:  use continuity.

Comment: And the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ meaning that $p/q$ can be chosen arbitrarily close to $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @lulu    We havent covered Continuity in lectures yet it seems to be the next chapter in the course is there any other way to deal with this type of question?

Comment: When $M$ is less than $1$ , we can always get $P/Q$ , a new rational number , between $\sin^{-1}(M)$ & $\sin^{-1}(1)$ , which makes $\sin(P/Q)$ larger than $M$.

Comment: Do you know that, say, $\sin (x)$ is monotonic in $[0, \pi/2]$?  That's enough (for sum, and the inf follows quickly).

Comment: @lulu I do know this fact that sin(x) is monotonic in this range and I could show that sin(x) is strictly increasing in this range via differentiation to show its a increasing function. Would this be sufficient justification to show that Sup(S) = 1?

Comment: @Prem So id have  M = 1 - ε where ε> 0 and that we can always find a P/Q such that 1>Sin(P/Q) > 1 - ε. As i think this is what our lecturer was trying to get us to prove.

Comment: That is Correct. No matter how close two real numbers are , we can always find a rational number between these two real numbers. Here , the two real numbers are $\sin^{-1}(M)$ & $\sin^{-1}(1)$ & a rational number between these two real numbers is $P/Q$ , thus , $\sin(P/Q)$ is between $M$ & $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $(M)<(1)$ is the UPPER BOUND.

Hence all rational numbers $(r)$ have $\sin(r)<(M)<(1)$
Hence $(r)<\sin^{-1}(M)<\sin^{-1}(1)$

Between two real numbers, we can always get a rational number.

There Exists $P/Q$ where $(r)<\sin^{-1}(M)<(P/Q)<\sin^{-1}(1)$

Hence $\sin(r)<(M)<\sin(P/Q)<(1)$

Contradiction :
$(M)<\sin(P/Q)$

Hence Assumption is not true.
Hence $(M)=(1)$ is the UPPER BOUND.